# Make ADL work with static member functions

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

My colleague defined a bunch of functions (which should be in my opinion free functions) inside a stateless class as static member functions.
Since this class is defined and uses types from a nested namespace, I'd like to use ADL to write less non-usefull code. But doesn't their choice just broke the purpose of ADL?

```
namespace nested_long_namespace_name
{
    struct type {};
    struct interface { static void f(type) {} };
}

int main()
{
    nested_long_namespace_name::type value{};
    f(value);                                        // ERROR (ADL does not kick in)
    interface::f(value);                             // ERROR (ADL does not kick in)
    nested_long_namespace_name::interface::f(value); // OK
}
```

Now, my question is: is there a workaround other that defining `f` as  a free function in the namespace `nested_long_namespace_name`?

Comment: Your colleague made unqualified lookup (from outside the class) impossible. So yes, no ADL.

Comment: If the namespace length is a problem, use a namespace alias.

Comment: You could use `auto& f = useless::f;` to bring `f` into the namespace scope, but sadly, that will also not be found via ADL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Argument-dependent lookup only finds declarations declared [in namespaces](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.argdep#3.sentence-3), and only happens during [unqualified lookup](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.argdep#1.sentence-1). So ADL would never apply to `interface::f(value)`, but it does apply to `f(value)`. But the name `f` is only going to be looked for under namespace `nested_long_namespace_name` - we're not going to continue looking in classes declared in those associated namespaces for static functions or data members that named `f`.

This follows the typical name lookup model - you can have a *using-directive* to bring a namespace into scope, but there's no equivalent to bring static class members into scope.

So yes, `interface::f` cannot be found by ADL.